# Is there any way to delay the driver initialization on Beaglebone Black?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'd like to know how can I find the driver information.
And I'd like to know if it's possible to delay driver initialization when I boot or reboot the Beaglebone Black.

Comment: Which driver? Some are going to be difficult (e.g., can't boot if you don't load the flash drivers); others would be fairly easy, e.g., if it's one that's a kernel module, you can delay loading the module. Also, why?

Answer (score 2):

Is the device driver opensource? If so, you'll want to download the source code so you can modify it.

Utilizing a multiple of the system clock, you delay the driver direction from within with the following code-snippet:

```
while (time_before(jiffies, j1))
    cpu_relax();
```

`j1` is the value of jiffies at the expiration of the delay
`cpu_relax` is a call that invokes architecture specifically to indicate an idle processor.

Again, all dependent on having the driver source code.

Comment: That approach has definite drawbacks. Busy waits are generally not ideal, and should only be used when the context is fully known.  cpu_relax() behaves in an architecture-specific and kernel configuration specific way (e.g. if preemption is not enabled it completely locks up the processor/core), and if interrupts happen to be disabled when the loop is entered, jiffies won't get updated. This method can make the device (in this case probably a 2-core ARM microcontroller) appear to lock up for awhile.

Answer (score 2):

If you can modify the driver, you can look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44189725/device-tree-probing-a-driver-and-avoiding-race-conditions/45110742#45110742).

My solution is to put `usleep_range(1000000, 12000000);` into the **probe** function in your driver, such that the driver will be delay 10 - 12 seconds. The **probe** function is where the driver start executing/initializing.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a busy loop that calls `cpu_relax()`, or `schedule()`, which have potential drawbacks, better is to use timer functions which are designed to wait without potentially adverse side effects (such as blocking other activities in such a way that could be awkward at best or cause the device to seize at worst).

For shorter delays (for example dealing with short latency issues), these may used:

```
#include <linux/delay.h>
void ndelay(unsigned long nsecs);
void udelay(unsigned long usecs);
void mdelay(unsigned long msecs);
```

Though probably not useful in this scenario, where driver initialization need to block and not return to the OS until the driver is initialized, generally, when you need to schedule an action to happen later, without blocking the current process, kernel timers are the way to go.

```
#include <linux/timer.h>
struct timer_list {
        /* ... */
        unsigned long expires;
        void (*function)(unsigned long);
        unsigned long data;
};

struct timer_list TIMER_INITIALIZER(_function, _expires, _data);

void init_timer(struct timer_list *timer);
void add_timer(struct timer_list * timer);
int del_timer(struct timer_list * timer);
int mod_timer(struct timer_list *timer, unsigned long expires);
int timer_pending(const struct timer_list * timer);
```

To use these, initialize a `timer_list` entry. The `TIMER_INITIALIZER()`, is a convenience function to do that, where it is passed a pointer to function to execute, opaque data to pass to the function, and a time `_expires` is the jiffy time at which the function should run.   *Note: The ellided fields in the `timer_list` struct are implementation details unneeded for this discussion.*

Then, calling `add_timer()` inserts the timer_list entry into the queue (e.g. 'starts' the timer).

Another possibility is to use something like `wait_event()`, which waits until some condition that is checked by the kernel before releasing the wait, wherein rather than waiting for an arbitrary amount of time, it waits until something happens T.B.D.